# What is the dart function type syntax for variable declaration?

Tags: dart

I know you can specify function types in formal arg list, but how would I do this for instance variables? I would like to do this:

```dart
class A<T> {
  int compare(T a, T b);
}
```

where compare is a function variable with the appropriate type. I would like to be able to write:

```dart
A a = new A();
a.compare = ...
```

Answer (score 45):

You can use [`typedef`](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#typedefs) :

```dart
typedef Comparison<T> = int Function(T a, T b);

class A<T> {
  Comparison<T> compare;
}

main() {
  A a = new A<int>();
  a.compare = (int a, int b) => a.compareTo(b);
  print(a.compare(1, 2));
}
```

Comment: Note that Dart already comes with a typedef for comparators: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Comparator.html

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the Alexandre Ardhuin's answer, direct declaration, without **typedef**:

```
class A<T> {
  late int Function(T a, T b) compare;
}

main() {
  A<int> a = new A<int>();
  a.compare = (int a, int b) => a.compareTo(b);
  print(a.compare(1, 2));
}
```